# Different between colour argument and aes colour in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use the colour in aes like this

```
ggplot(data=olympia,aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y=gold,colour="red")) + geom_line(aes(y=silver,colour="blue"))
```

it does not work.

If I use the colour argument it shows the right colours red and blue

```
ggplot(data=olympia,aes(x=year)) + geom_line(aes(y=gold),colour="red") + geom_line(aes(y=silver),colour="blue")
```

What is the different?
What's the fault?

Dataframe

```
year gold silver
1 2002   12     16
2 2006   11     12
3 2010   10     13
4 2014    8      3
```

Comment: Well, it's spelled `silver` in the first and `silber` in the second. Presumably your `olympia` dataset has the word `silver` misspelled as `silber` (you should have shown the dataset to confirm this).

Comment: Can you please show the result of `dput(head(olympia))` (edit it into the question rather than putting it in a comment)

Comment: Dataset \b year gold silver \b 1 2002 12 16 2 2006 11 12 3 2010 10 13 4 2014 8 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that when you provide the colour argument in `aes`, it treats it as a factor, and tries to map each level of the factor to a color (the same way it would if you gave `c("USA", "USA", "Russia", "Russia")`- it wouldn't treat them as literal colors).

In contrast, when you give the colour directly to `geom_line`, it takes it as an actual color. You can see this in the documentation for `geom_line`:

```
Usage:

       geom_line(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
         position = "identity", ...)
<snip>

     ...: other arguments passed on to ‘layer’. This can include
          aesthetics whose values you want to set, not map. See ‘layer’
          for more details.
```

Notice "**whose values you want to set, not map**".

Comment: The problem is that there won't be any legend when setting color directly to geom_line